# Handling multiple records in a html form with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am  new to HTML, PHP and Javascript. I was creating a user profile form which has details like Full Name, Email Id, Mobile etc.

In addition, I have to add a section for "Hobbies/Interests" which could include multiple records - such as Books, Travel, Hike, Marathon etc.

I need to add these hobbies as a separate section in the HTML form with the user having a "+" button to add more Interests and a single button to save all the records added using the + button.

How do I handle this when I post data to PHP form? I believe through javascript, I can have the functionality of adding more records to the Interests section. But how to handle this in PHP when the form is submitted.

Comment: So what are you using php for? Are you inserting values into a db?

Comment: Your question is too broad. All you have on server side is a `_POST` array, so use it.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the inputs through javascript, create them like this

```
<input type="text" name="hobbies[]">
```

When you receive the data in PHP, "hobbies" will be an array:

```
$hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
foreach ($hobbies as $hobby) {
  do something with the hobby ...
}
```

You can add specific indexes for your inputs if you prefer. This could be an internal ID for example, so you know if they delete one. If you don't specify indexes, it will just autoincrement them starting from 0

```
<input type="text" name="hobbies[12]">
<input type="text" name="hobbies[17]">
<input type="text" name="hobbies[67]">
```

Then reference the index:

```
foreach ($hobbies as $hobby_index => $hobby) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

make the array of hobbies in HTML form make name as `name=hobbies[];` and handle this array in php.
+ button can generate html code and here also generate `name=hobbies[]`. you can do this using jQuery `append()` function .

Comment: This question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

When the user adds a new hobby, do you want the hobby to be immediately added to the database or when the form is submitted finally ? If it's the former, use AJAX. Otherwise, (in alternative to other answers), you can have a hidden textbox, that collects a comma-separated list of all hobbies whenever user presses the +. That textbox will also be submitted as one of the _POST accessible elements. Then you can use the split function in PHP to loop through the items. 
p.s. I think using hidden elements may be considered a non-standard practice by some.